# linux script to run multiple commands at specific time

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I need some help in writing a Linux script that do the following:

```
command 1
command 2
wait 10 minutes
command 3
command 4
```

and this script should run automatically at specific time for example 4 am...

Thank in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a script.sh like:

```
#!/bin/bash

command 1
command 2
sleep 600 # 600 seconds = 10 min
command 3
command 4
```

And then create a cronjob:

```
0 4 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh
```

You can see more info of cron in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info

Answer (score 1):

if you want the job to run *once* at a future time, instead of cron use [`at`](http://man.cx/at)

```
at 4am tomorrow <<END
command 1
command 2
sleep 600
command 3
command 4
END
```

One of the advantages of `at` is that it will execute the commands using your *current* environment. The limited environment provided by cron is a cause of confusion for many people.